# Is there a way to unescape an escaped html string in FreeMarker?

Tags: freemarker

I have a FreeMarker template and the data being supplied to it is already escaped.

```
&lt;b&gt;Marmot&lt;/b&gt;
```

Is there a way to unescape it?

```
<b>Marmot</b>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no function for un-escaping (which would be a function for fixing corrupted data). But, are you sure that you get the data like that, and it's not FreeMarke that escapes it? `${something}` escapes the string if auto-escaping is on. Then you can use `${something?no_esc}` to prevent that. (Or if the template uses legacy auto-escaping, then `<#noescape>${something}</#noescape>`.)

Comment: I'm positive the data comes in like that.  I can get it to work by using ?replace, but it is not ideal.  Example: ?replace('&lt;', "\l")?replace('&gt;', "\g")

Comment: Proper HTML un-escaping is quite complicated though, unless you know the escaper to be simple. You should invoke an external tool, like maybe `org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4`, or Jsoup, if you can touch the Java part of the project.